# Connect NSOutlineView/NSTreeView into an NSArrayController?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to use Bindings with NSOutlineView.

I cannot see how to connect the "currently selected item" to anything else via Bindings

I've tried:

- use NSOutlineView directly, bind to
  "selection" (doesn't work; looking at
  the docs, Apple hasn't implemented
  that binding)
- use an NSArrayController, bind to "arrangedObjects", and bind the NSAC
  to the NSOV's "selectedRowIndexes"
  (doesn't work; you get a strange
  error message that "NSSet cannot be
  created from NSIndexSet"; (why not?
  surely, one is a subclass of the
  other?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use `NSArrayController` for an outline view, you use an `NSTreeController`. Then you can just bind to `yourTreeController.selectedObjects` if you want to access the selection.

`NSArrayController` is for use with `NSTableView`, `NSTreeController` is for use with `NSOutlineView`.

Apple has [a great example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView) showing how to use `NSOutlineView` with `NSTreeController`.

Answer (score 1):

NSOutlineView does support bindings:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSOutlineView.html

Comment: All the tutorials I could find via google claimed it didn't. Looking at the link you provide, I still can't see how to get the selection in a way that any other controller can use - I'll edit the question, thanks

Comment: You can bind the selectionIndexPaths to an NSArray property, this is where you will find the selections.

Comment: So, I'd end up with: NSOutlineView.selectionIndexPaths -bound to- NSArray instance on some class of mine -bound to- NSArrayController ?

Comment: No, (if I am not mistaken), you bind this to an NSArray property on some class of yours. That's it. And for the actual content you bind that to an NSTreeController object

Comment: ...but I need to get the output in the standard binding that other GUI elements can use - hence I'd need a separate NSArrayController on top of the array, I think? Or is that not possible, to do a 2-way bind on a single object?